# OpenStreetMap: building a weighted graph

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I would like to create a fairly big (~1bln nodes) weighted graph, with nodes being locations and edges being the roads that are present in OpenStreetMap data. Let us say we want to focus on some country, to keep the size within the above limit. The weights of the edges can be the actual lengths of the roads they represent. What would you do? Should I write my own parser for XML data and construct it in a straightforward way?

Answer (score 1):

You may find gis.stackoverflow.com useful. The keywords are PostGIS and pgRouting. See e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21680/collecting-street-data-to-populate-a-graph-stucture-for-routing/21682#21682
and similar questions.